# Casting from basic type to non-POD struct

Tags: c++

This question is whether casting a byte stream into a non-POD structure is undefined behaviour.

Where data is produced somewhere like this, i.e. packs 4 4-bit values into a `short`.

```
std::vector<unsigned short> v(50);
for(int i<0; k < 50; k++)
{
    v[k] = (k%8) | (k+1)%8 << 4 | (k+2)%8 << 8 | (k+2)%8 << 12
}
```

Then the data is passed to a second module as a byte stream and parsed in the receiving module.

```
struct Data
{
Data(unsigned short a, unsigned short b, unsigned short c, unsigned short d)
{
    value = (a & 0xF) | (b & 0xF) << 4 | (c & 0xF) << 8 | (d & 0xF) << 12
}

Data(unsigned short v) : value(v) {}

short getA() const
{
    return value & 0xF
}

short getB() const
{
    return (value >> 4) & 0xF
}

short getC() const
{
    return (value >> 8) & 0xF
}

short getD() const
{
    return (value >> 12) & 0xF
}

private:
    unsigned short value;
}
```

...

```
unsigned char* data = ...;
Data* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Data*>(data);

ptr[0].getA();
```

Is this undefined behaviour? The size of the `struct Data` is the same as `short`, but does the presence of a constructor and member functions make it UB? If I remove the constructors, will it then be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* to go through a constructor to construct an object. You can't simply cast a byte stream and then pretend that it results in a usable object.
For a [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type you can create the object first, then copy in bytes, but otherwise a constructor call is needed.

To answer your question: *Yes*, that would be UB.

Comment: This is true whether POD or not. The only types you're allowed to access without first creating an object of that actual type are `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`. For a trivially-copyable type, you can copy into an object byte-by-byte, but you must first create an actual object of the type.

Comment: @aschepler You are right. Thanks. Updated to hopefully clarify.

Comment: So even a simple type like struct Data{unsigned short value;}; would be UB?

Comment: @aschepler, so casting to a unsigned short* ptr would also be UB?

Comment: @thorsan From `Data*` to `unsigned short*`? That one would actually be okay, because `Data` and `unsigned short` are "pointer-interconvertible", and there actually is an object of type `unsigned short`.

Comment: @aschepler, sorry, I meant from unsigned char* to unsigned short*.
But if I know that the unsigned char memory size is a multiple of 4, would it still be UB if I cast to a type: struct Data{unsigned short value}; type?

Comment: And I was wrong about "the only types". Looks like you're allowed to use an aggregate or union that doesn't exist in some circumstances.

Comment: @aschepler and I'd advice _against_ doing so: this makes pretty fragile programs as it silently becomes UB as soon as you do the slightest modification to your types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. But you can find an easy alternative:

```
std::vector<unsigned short> in(50);
std::vector<Data> out{begin(in), end(in)};
(void) out[0].getA();
```

The construction of `out` will construct `Data` objects in-place from each element of `in`. And you can trust your compiler to [optimize away any memory copy](https://godbolt.org/z/OZo4sk) ;)

Comment: I see gcc optimizes away the copy, but this does not happen for MSVC 15, even with /Ox. Do you know how to make MSVC 15 optimize this away